# Server side Redirect related to online payment does not work

Tags: php, ajax, header

Redirect related to online payment does not work. When I send the request in Ajax.It cannot be redirected header. Please help

Everything works fine except redirecting
Sample My Codes

```js
         <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).on('click', '#btnkharid2', function(e){

    idservice = [];
$('.rowemkanat.activeservic').each(function(){
    idservice.push($(this).attr('id'));
});

    var senfiden='<?= model::encrypt_decrypt_idbasket('encrypt',  $pageid); ?>';
    var jbsid='<?= model::encrypt_decrypt_idbasket('encrypt',  $jbsid); ?>';
    var iddate=$('#sel_depart').find('.activedateset.activedatesetst').attr('data-value');
    var idsaat=$('#sel_size').find('.catitem.activetimes').attr('value');
    var banksel=$('.bankselect.activebank').attr('value');
    var nameisset=$('#btnkharid2').attr('name');

    $.ajax({
      url  : '<?= URL ?>nm/finishkharid/'+nameisset+'',
      type : 'POST',
      data:{'senfiden':senfiden,'idservice':idservice,'iddate':iddate,'idsaat':idsaat,'banksel':banksel,'jbsid':jbsid},
      beforeSend: function()
      {
        $("#btnkharid2").html('<div class="content"><div class="text">در حال اتصال به درگاه</div></div><div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i></div>');
      },
      success :  function(response)
      {
        if(response=="00106"){

          $("#infookprice").fadeIn(0, function(){
            //$(".bt-finished4").html('');
          });
        }
        else{
          $("#infookprice").fadeIn(0, function(){
            $("#infookprice").html('<div>'+response+'</div>');
          });
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

```
 header('location: https://www.zarinpal.com/pg/StartPay/'. $Authority);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that your api method for online payment is not allowed to prevent cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks. If you are using an online banking system, ask them about their XSS prevention protocol and work something out.